# Null eigenvector assumption: is it always true that for this non positive matrix $A$, there exists $v$ such that $A_{ij} v^{j} = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, ricci-flow

> Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and $A_t$ a $(0, 2)$ positive definite tensor defined in $M$ for all $t \in [t_0, t_1)$ and suppose that there exists $p \in M$ and $v \in T_p M$ such that $A(v, v) = 0$ at $(p, t_1)$. Does this imply that there exists a vector $\tilde{v}$ satisfying $A_{ij}\tilde{v}^{j} = 0$?

Context: when one proves the maximum principle for tensors, we define a certain $(0, 2)$ tensor that depends on time like that and it's necessary to prove that $A > 0$ for all $t \in [0, T)$ for a certain $T$. Proceeding by contradiction, we suppose that that's not true, so that there exists a point and instant $(p, t_1)$ such that $A > 0$ for all $t \in [t_0, t_1)$ but $A(v, v) = 0$ at $(p, t_1)$. I get that so far.

But the problem is that $A(v, v) = A_{ij}v^{i} v^{j} \neq A_{ij} v^{j}$. I don't see how $A_{ij}v^{i}v^{j} = 0$ implies that $A_{ij}v^{j} = 0$ (of course, if it were the other way around this would be trivial, but it's not).

[image]

Comment: Hint: try to show that $v$ is an eigenvector for the matrix representing $A$.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the hint! But I'm still having some trouble. The matrix representing $A$ applied to the vector $v$ is the vector whose $k$-th entries are given by $A_{kj}v^{j}$, which are not multiples of $v^{k}$. And even supposing that I could understand that, how would $v$ being such an eigenvector help me here?

Comment: Just posting in case the OP is interested. One can consider the so-called *Rayleigh quotient* $\frac{A(w,w)}{|w|^2}$ (where $A$ is real, symmetric). It can be shown that the infimum is the smallest eigenvalue of A, and it is achieved by the corresponding eigenvector of $A$. Then since $v$ is a minimizer here, it is an eigenvector of (the matrix representing) $A$. This answer the hint given by Thomas.

Comment: I appreciate your remarks, @Hopfeccentric! Thanks. I would also be really grateful if you posted some references for your claims "It can be shown that the infimum is the smallest eigenvalue of A, and it is achieved by the corresponding eigenvector of A.". Of course, don't get me wrong, I'm not doubting you in any way, it's just that I have no idea where in the literature that sort of stuff is proven.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade No worry. Well, the wikipedia page of Rayleigh quotient contains such statement, and you can also attempt it as an exercise (at least for the simplest case where A is a real symmetric $n\times n$ matrix). 

Sorry that I don't have a concrete reference apart from Wikipedia. Actually I first encountered this in a PDE course, where it is used to study the spectrum of the Laplacian. In this direction, Strauss's book may be good to check out.

Comment: @Hopfeccentric Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you have written I'm under the impression that you know that the map $w\mapsto A(w,w) $ has a minimum in $v$ (for fixed $(p, t_1)$).

But then it's derivative in $v$ is zero, and that's just the map $w\mapsto 2 A(v, w)$. So this then implies that $A(v, .) $ is zero.

Comment: I see! Thanks for answering, I appreciate it. But how is it that $v$ is a minimum of that map? I had made a similar argument to prove the scalar maximum principle where I proved a real value was a minimum, but I'm not sure it will adapt well here.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade From what you have written (again, I'm not really sure about the setup) you have a map which is positive ($A(w,w)>0 $ for every nonzero $w$ and every $p,t$ and, at a certain point $p_0, t_0$, $=0$ for the first time (at some value $v$). This implies that, for fixed $p_0, t_0$, $v$ is a minimizer. Assuming the map is continuous.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade If I did not understand the setup correctly, then, of course, the reasoning is not valid...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think you understood the setup but I'm still a little lost. We have that $A(w, w) > 0$ for every $0 \neq w$ and $t \in [t_0, t_1)$, and we know that there exists $p, t_1$ such that $A(v, v) = 0$ for some $0 \neq v \in T_pM$. But why couldn't there exist other non zero vectors $w$ such that $A(w, w) < 0$ at $(p, t_1)$? Also, yes, the map is continuous.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade By contradiction. Assume $ A(w,w)<0$. Then look at a sequence $t_n, p_n, w_n$ converging to $t_0, p_0, w$. For large  $n$, $w_n \neq 0$, so  $A(w_n, w_n) > 0 $. So, in the limit, it cannot become negative. Sorry for renaming the points in question.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks for your patience! I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade One more remark: This reasoning makes use of the fact that $A(v,v)=0$. If $A(v,v)$ were only extremal you would only be able to conclude that $A(v,w)=0$ on a hyperplane. This reasoning is the analytical proof for the existence of an eigenvector for symmetric matrices, in that case one restricts the map to the unit sphere.